# Not able to fetch value from jenkins console output file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I need to get value from my Jenkins console output and save it to a variable. Below is my code

```
stage('Publish') {
    steps 
    {
        script
        {
      bat 'gradle publish'
        }
      def out = bat(script:"gradle publish", returnStdout: true )
     Pattern p = Pattern.compile("INFO] Upload: .*zip")
    Matcher m = p.matcher(out);
    echo "value to be printed"
    echo out
```

After running the pipeline echo statements are not showing in console. i need to save a value from console output which is like Upload http://localhost:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/com/xxx/xxx.zip

Comment: move that 5 code lines after `script` code block  into the `script`.

Comment: it didn't work -young